# Magic Square java array index out of bounds exception can someone please enlighten me why there's an error in my code

Tags: java

I don't know why this code results to an error I already tried visualizing the inputs and my observations doesn't result to an error but for some reason this code throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I'm gonna need a fresh pair of eyes in this community. Please help me.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MagicSquare {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        int j = n / 2;
        int[][] magicSquare = new int[i][j];
        for (int num = 1; num <= n * n;) {
            if (i < 0 && j < 0) {
                i = n - 2;
                j = 0;
            }
            else {
                if (j < 0) {
                    j = j - 1;
                }
                if (i < 0) {
                    i = n - 1;
                }
            }
            if (magicSquare[i][j] != 0) { // ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on this line
                j = j + 1;
                i = n - 1;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                magicSquare[i][j] = num;
                num = num + 1;
            }
            i = i - 1;
            j = j - 1;
        }
        for (i = 0; i <= magicSquare.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j <= magicSquare[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(magicSquare[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter a number: 3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at baseproj/baseproj.MagicSquare.main(MagicSquare.java:31)
```

I've tried arranging the inputs on a piece of paper and it still won't work

Comment: Could you explain what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: This code writes a 3x3 2d array whose sums of rows and columns results to 15

Comment: The range of an array's indices is `0..size-1`. Your array's size is `i,j` and you try to use `i` and `j` as indices.

Comment: `new int[i][j]` is equivalent to `new int[0][j]` here. That shouldn't be what you want.

Comment: Because `i` is zero when this line of code is executed: `int[][] magicSquare = new int[i][j];` it means that the array `magicSquare` has zero rows. It seems that `i` should be greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the array like this:

```
int[][] magicSquare = new int[n][];
```

And initialize each row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    magicSquare[i] = new int[n];
}
```